# Where does Camtasia store files locally?

Tags: audio

I uploaded them as guest, but they are not listed online even though I provided a valid email address. Windows 7

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a little more information? Just reading this right now is slightly confusing... Did you try uploading to a website, or just producing a video locally?

Comment: Also, letting us know what platform and OS may be of use. If this is Windows for instance, look in the "documents and settings" (Win7) or "Users" (Win8) for the login that was implementing Comtasia at the time.

Comment: Actually guys the website says that it won't save it locally once the internet connection becomes available.